# jquery highlight table row if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I know how to highlight a table row, if I "click" an element.

But when I open a page, some checkboxes are already checked.  I want to highlight those rows, using jquery, when the page loads.

I gave all my checkboxes a class of "checkboxes".
Here's what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   if( $('.checkboxes').attr("checked") == true ){ /*not sure how to detect a row*/  }

});
```

I'm not sure what to put inside.

The closest I got was to place this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').addClass("pinkrow");
```

But the `$(this)` obviously doesn't detect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.each()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [`:checked` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo selector:

```
$('tr .checkboxes:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('pinkrow');
});
```

If you want to use pure CSS selectors only, you can test whether an element is checked with the DOM element's `checked` property:

```
$('tr .checkboxes').each(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('pinkrow');
    }
});
```

Also note that `tr .checkboxes` only selects those `.checkboxes` elements, which are in a table row (in case there are others).

Comment: I didn't even consider the .each() selector.  Nice. thanks for the reminder.